# What is the Picard group of a Schubert variety in the affine Grassmannian?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, affine-grassmannian, picard-group

I'm not sure I have a lot more to say than the title.  Let $G$ be your favorite simple algebraic group over $\mathbb{C}$, and let $$\overline {\mathrm{Gr}}_\lambda= \overline{G(\mathbb{C}[[t]])\cdot t^\lambda \cdot G(\mathbb{C}[[t]])}/ G(\mathbb{C}[[t]]).$$ It's a commonly cited theorem that $\overline {\mathrm{Gr}}_\lambda$ is a projective variety for every $\lambda$, but the usual tricks for finding the Picard group of a Schubert variety in the finite dimensional case don't work (the group $G(\mathbb{C}[[t]])$ is perfect if $G$ is semi-simple).  Is this Picard group computed anywhere in the literature?

Comment: Just to check, you mean finite dimensional, not finite codimensional Schuberts, right? (Not that I know the answer either way.)

Comment: The proof of Proposition 13.2.19 in Kumar's "Kac-Moody groups, their flag varieties and representation theory" might provide what you want.

Comment: Yes, I mean finite-dimensional ones.

Comment: I would try Olivier Matthieu's monograph (in French) - Asterisque 159-160.

Comment: I suspect you want to define your Schubert variety as a single, rather than as a double quotient.

Comment: Yeah, I went a little overboard there.  On the other hand, I don't think it should make a difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[From the comments] The proof of Proposition 13.2.19 in Kumar's "Kac-Moody groups, their flag varieties and representation theory" appears to provide the requested information.

Comment: Alexander Woo's suggestion of Mathieu's Asterisque 159-160 monograph is also potentially useful, it contains a chapter "Groupe de Picard des varietes de Schubert" but I cannot speak for its contents since I haven't read it. 